# When app is closed how can i use local notification from sqlite data in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter Issue for background processing

> How to show local notification from sqlite while app is closed in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Try [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), code snippet from the [sample example app](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/example).

```
  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: 'item x');
  }
```

It also has the option to schedule an Notification, and route based on the Notification clicked.